# tkinter after() with arguments

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to launch a function (trace_myshot), which traces a line over a canvas, every 500ms.

```
   def trace_shot(self, listshots, indexshot):
        shot = listshots[indexshot]
        self.mycanvas.trace_myshot(
                    shot, listshots[indexshot + 1].hit_x, listshots[indexshot + 1].hit_y
                )
        if (indexshot + 1) < len(listshots):
            self.after(500, self.trace_shots, listshots, indexshot + 1)

    def trace_shots(self, listshots: list[Shot]):
        self.trace_shot(listshots, 0)
```

I got an error saying I m calling trace_shot() with 3 arguments instead of 2 in self.after(). How can I fix that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`trace_shots` accepts two arguments (`self`, `listshots`) and you're passing it three, just like the error says.

When you do `self.after(500, self.trace_shots, listshots, indexshot + 1)`, `trace_shots` receives `self` as the first argument, `listshots` as the second argument, and then there is a third argument `indexshot + 1` that `trace_shots` doesn't expect.